# how to call an ipython within virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, ipython

Good time of the day, everyone!

The problem is the following:

1. I create `virtualenv` using the command `python3 -m venv env` (my python version `3.8.9`)
2. I activate it `. ./env/bin/activate`
3. Install ipython: `pip install ipython`
4. Try to run it `ipython`, but instead of invoking my virtualenv's ipython, My system ipython open with the following message:

```
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:852: UserWarning: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
  warn(
```

What should I do to change this behaviour and to be able to call my virtualenv's ipython?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alias to indicate ipython in your virtual env. First make sure you have activated your virtualenv `source ./env/bin/activate`. Then run:

```
alias ipython="python -c 'import IPython; IPython.terminal.ipapp.launch_new_instance()'"
```

This is a great way of always being sure that the ipython instance always belongs to the virtualenv's python version. And This works only on ipython >2.0.

Source: [Link](https://coderwall.com/p/xdox9a/running-ipython-cleanly-inside-a-virtualenv)